# Unable to return Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.File object Names filtered by extension

Tags: client-object-model, linq

I'm attempting to retrieve a set of File objects filtered by extension.  The following code works correctly (without the filter).

```
FolderCollection productModelFolders = _clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(PRODUCT_MODELS_LIST).RootFolder.Folders;
_clientContext.Load(productModelFolders, folders => folders.Include(folder => folder.Name, folder => folder.ServerRelativeUrl));
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Folder productModelFolder = productModelFolders.Single(folder => folder.Name == "models");
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

_clientContext.Load(productModelFolder, items => items.Folders);
_clientContext.Load(
    productModelFolder.Folders,
    folders => folders.Include(
        folder => folder.Folders,
        folder => folder.Name,
        folder => folder.ServerRelativeUrl,
        folder => folder.Folders.Include(
            modelFolder => modelFolder.Name,
            modelFolder => modelFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
            modelFolder => modelFolder.Files,
            modelFolder => modelFolder.Files.Include(
                file => file.Name,
                file => file.ServerRelativeUrl
            )
        )
    )
);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

However, when I add the Where clause to implement the filter:

```
    folder => folder.Folders.Include(
        modelFolder => modelFolder.Name,
        modelFolder => modelFolder.ServerRelativeUrl,
        modelFolder => modelFolder.Files,
        modelFolder => modelFolder.Files.Include(
            file => file.Name,
            file => file.ServerRelativeUrl
        ).Where(file => file.Name.Substring(file.Name.Length - FILE_EXTENSION.Length) == FILE_EXTENSION)
    )
```

I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll

Additional information: The 'Substring' member cannot be used in the expression.
```

In my various searches for an answer I've seen multiple articles that essentially say SharePoint can't handle the conversion from Linq expression to SharePoint.

What is the accepted/correct way to overcome this?

(Note: The included code is not complete/optimized.  Please do **NOT** mention any other issues unless they specifically relate to the question at hand).

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LINQ you could use CAML:
[Get files by file extension.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8cf10fec-b285-4066-b617-ca79bb372553/#e766cb89-5ed2-4386-bb83)
[Get files by file type.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20692247)

If using LINQ is very important you either have to fetch all files and then filter them by LINQ (much more data over the network, but easier to read and write the code). You can do this by calling `ToList().Where(file => ...)` on your collection after `ExecuteQuery`.
Or you could look at [SPMetal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538255(v=office.14).aspx), although personally I have bad experiences with that.